# Why I don't have access to generic type class elements?

Tags: java, generics, kotlin, types, interface

I have made a generic function in Kotlin in which I want to instantiate a generic type.

```
interface TickerEntity{

  val tickers: Array<String>
  val fee: Double
  val bid : Double
  val ask : Double

}

  inline fun < reified T : TickerEntity> getStockBuySell() {

    val tickerEntity:Class<T> = T::class.java

  }
```

**TickerEntity** is an interface. I intend to instantiate classes which implement it

Function above is kind of working, BUT I don't have access to each class elements. It also seems that constructor of none of them is initiated.

**My question:** how to correctly instantiate an interface in above example? I want to have access to each class elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create an instance of it, you can call `newInstance()` on the Java class, provided it has a zero-argument constructor:

```
inline fun < reified T : TickerEntity> getStockBuySell() {
    val tickerEntity : T = T::class.java.newInstance()
    // ...
}
```

This will fail if the class does not have a zero-argument constructor.

You might consider taking a constructor as the argument of your function.

```
fun <T : TickerEntity> getStockBuySell(entityConstructor: () -> T) {
    val tickerEntity : T = entityConstructor()
    // ...
}

// Usage:
getStockBuySell(::MyTickerEntityImplementationClass)
```

The above usage still necessitates a zero-argument constructor, but if you had some special implementation that needs arguments, you could pass them via lambda:

```
getStockBuySell { MyTickerEntityImplementationClass("someConstructorArgument") }
```